# Use underscore throttle in objects - How to keep object's reference?

Tags: underscore.js, throttling

I'm trying to use `_.throttle` in an object but I think I haven't understand how to do this correctly.

I use jQuery and Underscore.js

```
function object() {
    this.throtthled = function () {
        // This should alert 1
        alert(this.var);
    }

    this.fastFunc = _.throttle(this.throtthled, 100);
    this.var = 1;
}


$(function () {    
    var myObject = new object();
    $(document).on('mousemove', myObject.fastFunc);    
});
```

But as you can see on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sukf3f3e/1/), this only returns `undefined` in console. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're accessing `this.throtthled` before having created it.

Comment: You're right. I've fixed it and can't access to `this.var`. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're accessing `this.throtthled` before having created it, passing `undefined` to `_.throttle` instead of a function (which had an `.apply` method).

Also, you need to [use the correct `this` context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) for your callback.

```js
// using the prototype:
function MyObject() {
    this.fastFunc = _.throttle(this.throttled.bind(this), 100);
    this.var = 1;
}
MyObject.prototype.throttled = function () {
    // This does alert 1
    alert(this.var);
};
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. What if I want to give fastFunc a parameter ?

Comment: Just give `throttled` a parameter. `_.throttle` passes any given arguments through.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have a deeper look at Prototype.

Comment: The prototype is not actually required for this solution, you just have to take that method from somewhere (prototype, static variable, constructor-defined function etc) and `bind` it